# Bootstrap 5 - Mobile Menu doesn't open

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm already stucked at this problem since days. I could not find any solutions anywhere, so I am asking the experts here :-)

I can not open my mobile menu. Nothing is happening.

It looks like:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <img src="/static/img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    id="toggleMobileNav" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-mobile" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mobile-nav-link"href="/#features">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mobile-nav-link"href="/#download">Download</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mobile-nav-link" href="/about">About us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
   
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Meanwhile I already replaced it with the code given at the official docs of bootstraps5 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/)

I watched several youtube-videos, where they just paste it and it worked. Not even the example from bootstrap5 docs work.. Can anyone spot a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got all the required javascript embedded on your page?

Comment: Your code works fine: https://codeply.com/p/PBoMqCl01d -- make sure you're properly including bootstrap.js

Comment: thank you, somehow the required js disappeared :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to start from here;

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

The code definitely works if you've incorporated bootstrap properly. It definitely sounds like your missing some essentials, such as the javascript required.

I'd always recommend starting from the beginning than the middle or the end in anything.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <img src="/static/img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    id="toggleMobileNav" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-mobile" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mobile-nav-link"href="/#features">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mobile-nav-link"href="/#download">Download</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mobile-nav-link" href="/about">About us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
   
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <!-- THIS IS AN IMPORTANT PART -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The videos you might be watching are already assuming you've got the basics done.

Follow the guide I've linked, it even contains a starter template that you can use and build from. It's basically what I did and then copied and pasted your code in the relevant area for it to work.